# Finding the modes of an array

Tags: javascript, array

I've a working function. But it feels complicated and doesn't look too good, I would like to improve it.

```
function Modes(arrays) {
    var frequency = {}; // array of frequency.
    var maxFreq = 0; // holds the max frequency.
    var modes = [];

    for (var j in arrays) {
        frequency[arrays[j]] = (frequency[arrays[j]] || 0) + 1; // increment frequency.

        if (frequency[arrays[j]] > maxFreq) { // is this frequency > max so far ?
            maxFreq = frequency[arrays[j]]; // update max.
        }
    }

    for (var i in frequency) {
        if (frequency[i] === maxFreq) {
            modes.push(i);
        }
    }

    result = modes.map(Number);              // makes string to numbers.
    return result.sort(function(a, b) {return a - b;});   // sorting the numbers from smallest to largest.
}

Modes(Array);
```

For example, given:

```
var Array = [9, -8, 1, 2, 4, -8, 7, 1, 5, 7]
```

then `Modes(Array)` gives:

```
[-8, 1, 7]
```

Comment: Not sure what the code does. It looks like it's expected to accept an array of arrays, but your example passes it a single array.

Comment: You should clearly mention something like *"This code obtains the repeated elements in the original array."*

Answer (score 1):

1. You might want to rename your function to make it clear what it's doing. Usually it helps to put function names in the form of a verb or action. Since it's returning a value, and doesn't modify the parameters, I'd probably go with `getModes()` or even `getModesFromNumArray()`.
2. You don't need to save the result of `modes.map(Number)` to a new variable; you can sort and return that result immediately without affecting the original array.

   ```
   return result.map(Number).sort(function(a,b){return a-b;});
   ```
3. You're looping twice as much as you need to!

   You can eliminate the need to loop through all your frequencies after already looping through all the items in the array by keeping track of your modes in the first loop.

   To do this, create a new array of modes every time the max frequency is exceeded, and append to that array every time the max frequency is reached.
4. Minor nitpick with your comments: `var frequency = {};` is creating an object, not an array. While we're there, shouldn't that read "frequencies" instead of merely "frequency" since it contains the frequency for each number encountered?

Your final function might end up looking like this:

```
function getModes(arr) {
  var frequencies = {};
  var maxFrequency = 0;
  var modes =[];
  for (var i in arr) {
    var currentCount = (frequencies[arr[i]] || 0) + 1;
    frequencies[arr[i]] = currentCount;
    if (currentCount === maxFrequency) {
      modes.push(arr[i]); // add the current number to the modes array
    } else if (currentCount > maxFrequency) {
      maxFrequency = currentCount;
      modes = [arr[i]]; // set modes to a new array containing the current number
    }
  }
  return modes.map(Number).sort();
}
```

Here's a working example:

```js
function getModes(arr) {
  var frequencies = {};
  var maxFrequency = 0;
  var modes = [];
  for (var i in arr) {
    var currentCount = (frequencies[arr[i]] || 0) + 1;
    frequencies[arr[i]] = currentCount;
    if (currentCount === maxFrequency) {
      modes.push(arr[i]); // add the current number to the modes array
    } else if (currentCount > maxFrequency) {
      maxFrequency = currentCount;
      modes = [arr[i]]; // set modes to a new array containing the current number
    }
  }
  return modes.map(Number).sort(function(a,b){return a-b;});
}
var array = [];
var input = document.getElementById("input");
var output = document.getElementById("output");
document.getElementById("add").addEventListener("click", function() {
  array.push(input.value);
  input.value = "";
  output.innerHTML = "Array: "+array;
});
document.getElementById("find").addEventListener("click", function() {
  output.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend","<div>Modes: "+ getModes(array)+"</div>");
  array = [];
});
```

```html
<input id="input" type="text" />
<input type="button" id="add" value="Add number to array" />
<div id="output"></div>
<input type="button" id="find" value="Find Modes" />
```